# Bad Word Filter, how do I replace words by their length?

Tags: php

I have this PHP Code, it generates random characters where there is a bad word:

```
$wordreplace = array (
  "!",
  "#",
  "@",
  "&",
  "^",
  "$",
  "%",
  "*"
);

class badword {
  function word_fliter($content) {
    global $badwords, $wordreplace;
    $count = count($badwords);
    $countfilter = count($wordreplace);
    // Loop through the badwords array
    for ($n = 0; $n < $count; ++$n, next ($badwords)) {
      //Create random replace characters
      $x = 2;
      $y = rand(3,5);
      $filter = "";
      while ($x<="$y") {
        $f = rand(0,$countfilter);
        $filter .="$wordreplace[$f]";
        $x++;
      }

      //Search for badwords in content
      $search = "$badwords[$n]";
      $content = preg_replace("'$search'i","<i>$filter</i>",$content);
    }
    return $content;
  }
}
```

However, I need it to generate asterisks equal to the number of letters in the bad word.

Answer (score 2):

You might be overthinking this. The whole first part of your code is meant to find a randomized replacement for the bad word. Only those last two lines matter, and you can replace them with:

```
$content = preg_replace_callback(
    $badwords,
    function ($matches) {
        return str_repeat('*', strlen($matches[0]));
    },
    $content
);
```

To make this work, though, you need to wrap your badwords in a 'capture group' like so:

```
$capture_badwords = [];
foreach ($word in $badwords) {
    $capture_badwords[] = "/(".$word.")/";
}
```

This should produce an array like this:

```
["/(abadword)/", "/(anotherbadword)/", "/(afourletterword)/", ... ]
```

[`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) lets you define a function with which you can manipulate the matched group.

Putting this together in an example:

```
$badwords = [ "/(dog)/", "/(cat)/", "/(here)/" ];
//"#\((\d+)\)#"
$phrase = "It is just dogs chasing cats in here.";

echo preg_replace_callback(
        $badwords,
        function ($matches) {
            return str_repeat('*', strlen($matches[0]));
        },
        $phrase
    );
```

Yields:

> It is just ***s chasing ***s in ****.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer :) But do you know a way to not limit these bad word filters to $phrase? I have a user's page and it has Presentation and a guestbook, I need it to detect the whole page, is that possible?

Comment: You can pass the entire page result through this function before returning it to the client. But I would need to know more about your particular setup before I could recommend a course of action.

Answer (score 2):

for replace bad words in string you can use preg_replace_callbackto perform a regular expression search and replace using a callback.

below example replace all bad words with `*`

output :

> PHP is a ***ular general-purpose scripting language that is especially
>   suited to web *****opment.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

// array of bad words to filter 
$badwords = array('pop','devel');

// strin to clean from bad words  
$text = 'PHP is a popular general-purpose scripting language that is especially suited to web development.';
// with /\w+/ regex we send each word to  replace_badwords function 
$text = preg_replace_callback('/\w+/', 'replace_badwords', $text);

echo $text;

// replace_badwords check if string has bad word then its replace with * char or not return otrginal word
function replace_badwords($ocr) {
  global $badwords;
  $newstr=false;
  foreach ($badwords as $key => $value) {

        $start = strpos($ocr[0],$value);
        if($start!== false){
            $length = strlen($value);
            $newstr = substr_replace($ocr[0],str_repeat("*",$length),$start,$length);
        }

        }

    return $newstr ? $newstr :  $ocr[0];

}

?>
```

Comment: I would be cautious about this solution for the following reasons: utilizing global keywords is not recommended, it loops through every bad word for every word found, the word capture/replacement is awkward to say the least. Finally, I'm not sure this even compiles?

Comment: It may be the unclear formatting, or PHP's unnatural permissiveness, but your `foreach` brace is never closed.